# .addClass on element in functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I can't figure out how to solve this. In header.php I have this javascript

```
  <script language="javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".catfilter").click(function(){
           $("#category-post-content").addClass("shownewsajax");
           $(".sasasa").addClass("rrrrrrrrrrrr");
     });     
    }); 
    </script>
```

It works perfectly for #category-post-content, but since the "sasasa" element is in functions.php (into add_action function), the class "rrrrrrrr" will not be added on .catfilter click.

Any ideas of how to make it work even if element that need the class is in functions.php?

This is the code in functions.php where .sasasa is

```
///Ajax post filtering by category
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_load-filter', 'prefix_load_cat_posts' );
 function prefix_load_cat_posts () { ?>
 <div class="allposts row blogrow">
 <?php ob_start ();
 $query = new WP_Query(
    $args = array (
    'showposts' => 999,
    'cat' => $cat_id = $_POST[ 'cat' ]
 )  );
 $posts = get_posts( $args );
  foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
 setup_postdata( $post );
 ?>

<div class="sasasa news-wrap">  
<div class="newsflex">
<div class="postfeat"> <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID ), 'my-custom-thumb' ); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>">
<?php endif; ?> 
 </div>
 <div class="postinfo">
 <div class="postcat">
 <?php foreach( (get_the_category($post)) as $category) { ?> <?php echo $category->cat_name; ?><?php } ?>
 </div>
 <h4 class="newstitle"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h4>
 <div class="postexc"><?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt($post); echo   $excerpt;?></div>
 <a href="<?php echo get_permalink; ?>">READ MORE <span    class="rightarrow"></span></a>
 </div>
 </div>
  </div>


 <?php
 } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
<div class="next-button"><a href="#" id="loadMoreCat">Load More Posts    CAT</a></div>

  <? $response = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();

   echo $response;
  die(1);
  }
```

Comment: You should wrap you javascript with `$(document).ready(function() {}):`

Comment: can you give use the HTML code where set .sasasa item ?

Comment: Also we have no idea how you include "functions.php" - since this is NOT a PHP issue, please click `<>` and post the HTML and script in a [mcve]

Comment: Inazo i added the code, can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".catfilter").click(function(){
      $("#category-post-content").addClass("shownewsajax");
      $(".sasasa").addClass("rrrrrrrrrrrr");
  });   
});
```

try this. this will execute when everything in your page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The `.sasasa` elements are added dynamically using Ajax. So when the jQuery function is parsed, those elements aren't present. If you start from the `document` and `.find()` those elements, it should work.

`.catfilter` seems to be static...

```
<script language="javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".catfilter").click(function(){
     $("#category-post-content").addClass("shownewsajax");
     $(document).find(".sasasa").addClass("rrrrrrrrrrrr");
  });     
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Try to debug it using some console logs. Something like `console.log("There is "+$(document).find(".sasasa").length+" .sasasa elements.")`, for example...